# PIC32MZ NVM write operation is improper

Tags: microchip, mplab, pic32

I'm using PIC32MZ2048EFG100, MPLAB X IDE(v5.00), Harmony(V2.06) and ICD 3 debugger.

In my project, I've configured the address 0x9D100000 (up to 432KBytes) for NVM operations to store some data.
To verify the NVM operation, I'm just doing NVM operation for the first block only. i.e address 0x9D100000.
I've erased(16KBytes) the 0th block(address 0x9D100000) and I read device memory and the result is correct. i.e all 0xFF values.

Now I'll write(2Kbytes) into this memory(address 0x9D100000) using 2Kbytes buffer which is set to value 0x55.
After writing, if I read device memory, only some of the addresses will be set with the value 0x55 and the rest of the memory will be set with the 0x00 value.

Why this memory is getting corrupted?
Please help me to know the details to resolve the issue.

Thank you

Comment: I have no experience of this, but perhaps you could describe which bytes are 0x55 and which are 0x00?

Comment: Maybe show some code.

Comment: I use the following MPLAB Harmony function for NVM operations.
For Erase: 
DRV_NVM_Write(nvm_data.NVMHandle, &nvm_data.NVMCommandHandle, sourceBuffer, blockStart, nBlock);
For Write:
DRV_NVM_Write(nvm_data.NVMHandle, &nvm_data.NVMCommandHandle, sourceBuffer, blockStart, nBlock);
For Read:
DRV_NVM_Read(nvm_data.NVMHandle, &nvm_data.NVMCommandHandle, targetBuffer, blockStart, nBlock);

The 0x55 and 0x00 bytes are random. But most of the bytes are 0x00

Comment: Please edit your question with the code snipet. It's hard to read without any formatting